# How to fix HSQL DataSource + TxM where identity always return 0

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions, hsqldb, jta

I am using Hibernate to do my ORM stuff w/ HSQL for tests. It seems that a connection is fetched to do the insert and then returned. Straight after that HIbernate gets a connection then tries to fetch the identity from HSQL but that returns 0 which is obviously wrong.

WHen i was running w/out a tm and datasource using a plain pooled connection everything worked but with the new tm + ds i am getting this problem.

Comment: Are you certain that you're querying for the identity after the persistence context has been flushed to the database?  Hibernate doesn't guarantee access to the generator until then, typically this happens when you close a transaction or close the session.  Also, what identity generator strategy are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the DataSource should be tx aware, so that connections are sticky for each new tx. The original problem was a different connection was used to fetch the identity of the new row which of course resulted in 0 being returned. If the connection remained sticky for the initial insert and call identity then everything works.

Comment: Hey mP, can you elaborate on your answer? I am having a similar problem and I tried different solutions, to avail. How can I make a DataSource tx aware?