# Auto-incrementation with HSQLDB (2.2.8) + DDLUtils

Tags: java, hsqldb, auto-increment, ibatis, ddlutils

I want to use HSQLDB as an embedded database but am having trouble getting it to **auto-increment**.

As far as I understand, `[CALL] IDENTITY()` can be used to get the last primary key value. However, experiments through both iBatis and HSQLDB's `DatabaseManagerSwing` continually return a 0 value.

How can I get auto-incrementation to work with HSQLDB?

Edit:

I didn't mention that I'm using [DDLUtils](http://db.apache.org/ddlutils/) to autogenerate tables. The following *does not* suit HSQLDB:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE database SYSTEM "http://db.apache.org/torque/dtd/database.dtd">

<database name="testdb">

    <table name="users">
        <!-- using autoincrement attribute below causes
        "primary key already exists" exception -->
        <column name="id" type="INTEGER" primaryKey="true" />
        <column name="username" type="VARCHAR" size="30" />
        <column name="password" type="VARCHAR" size="100" />
    </table>

</database>
```

Also, here is the iBatis SQL map used for the domain class:

```
<insert id="insertUser" parameterClass="user">
    <selectKey keyProperty="id" resultClass="int">
        CALL IDENTITY()
    </selectKey>
INSERT INTO USERS
( USERNAME, PASSWORD ) 
VALUES
( #username#, #password#)       
</insert>
```

Comment: What version of HSQLDB do you use?

Comment: @EmmanuelBourg It's 2.2.8 which is probably the latest.

Comment: This might be the source of the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4857730/how-to-fix-hsql-datasource-txm-where-identity-always-return-0

Comment: Another related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456742/hsqldb-ignores-first-insert-operation-on-table-at-server-server-needs-to-be-wa

Comment: @EmmanuelBourg Do you have ties with Apache? The issue simply had to do with how the table was being generated through DDLUtils.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an example that prints out

```
0
1
2
```

on my machine:

```
import java.io.File;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Date;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    File dbDir = new File("/tmp/identity_test"); 
    String connectionTemplate = "jdbc:hsqldb:file:%s/test";
    String connStr = String.format(connectionTemplate, dbDir);
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connStr, "", "");
    Statement s = connection.createStatement();
    s.execute("CREATE TABLE test (id INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, s VARCHAR(10))");
    PreparedStatement psInsert = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO test (s) VALUES (?)");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      psInsert.setString(1, "hello");
      psInsert.executeUpdate();
      PreparedStatement psIdentity = connection.prepareStatement("CALL IDENTITY()");
      ResultSet result = psIdentity.executeQuery();
      result.next();
      int identity = result.getInt(1);
      result.close();
      System.out.println(identity);
    }
    connection.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: The SQL you used to create the table provided the solution: `GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY`. I didn't mention I was using Apache DDLUnit to generate the tables automatically using XML. I will seek another framework for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

If you use an ORM, they will perform the identity column work for you. [sormula](http://www.sormula.org/) makes it easy with an annotation. See org.sormula.tests.identity package within the project for examples.

Row class defined:

```
public class IdentityTest
{
    @Column(identity=true)
    int id;
    ...
```

From org.sormula.identity.tests.InsertTest:

```
 IdentityTest row = new IdentityTest(-1, "Insert one");
 assert getTable().insert(row) == 1 : "insert one failed";
 assert row.getId() > 0 : "indentity column was not generated";
```

HSQLDB is included in the tests.